# What argon2id parameters should I adjust

Tags: hash, argon2

I am currently running argon2id of hashing function with below parameters on my IphoneXS:

Iterations: 8, Memory: 64MB, Parallelism: 8, HashLength: 32,

These params allow hashing time to be less than 1s.

So is there a formula to calculate the argon2id parameters?

I want to find the optimized parameters. Should I favor Iterations or Memory? The total hashing time will still be less than 1 that means iterations or memory will increase and based on that iteration or memory will decrease.

Comment: What effect do you want?

Comment: I want to find the optimized parameters. Should I favor Iterations or Memory? The total hashing time will still be less than 1 that means iterations or memory will increase and based on that iteration or memory will decrease.

Comment: Optimised for performance? What outcome do you want?

Comment: I want to find which way is better.

Comment: "Better" to accomplish what, though?

Comment: You've asked this a few times, and we keep asking the same things. You need to be able to answer what we are asking before we can figure out what "good" looks like in your context. It's like asking, "what's the best vehicle?" It depends. Best for what? Crossing the ocean? Going to space? Going to the store in an environmentally friendly way?

Comment: To give you examples of outcomes you may want: "I want parameters that make hashing take at least 1.5 seconds so that brute force attacks take longer". Another, different goal could be "I want to tweak the parameters so that hashing on the IPhoneXS still takes below 1sec, but make it harder for things like Raspberry Pi to brute force the hashes".

Comment: I'm trying to help you. You are not helping us to help you. As the answer that you accepted stated, even he can't help you without more info. Just answer our questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [OWASP Password Storage Cheat Sheet](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet.html#argon2id) gives the following general recommendation (based on [discussion of cracking rates from March 2021](https://github.com/OWASP/CheatSheetSeries/issues/595#issuecomment-802414213)):

> Argon2id should use one of the following configuration settings as a base minimum which includes the minimum memory size (m), the minimum number of iterations (t) and the degree of parallelism (p).
>
> - m=37 MiB, t=1, p=1
> - m=15 MiB, t=2, p=1
>
> Both of these configuration settings are equivalent in the defense they provide. The only difference is a trade off between CPU and RAM usage.

So those are probably a good starting point. But without knowing your use case or objectives, no one can really say whether they're they're "better" or "more optimised" than the parameters you've posted, or than the defaults of whatever library you're using.